# can't delete data eloquent in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

i want to delete eloquent data from 2 tables. Table dosen and users.

eloquent : id and user_id

1.users(id, name, username, email, password, admin, remember_token, updated_at, created_at)

2.dosen (iddosen, user_id, namadosen, nipy, alamatdosen, notelpdosen, etc)

this is my method :

```
 public function destroy($id)
{       
$dosenUpdate = Request::all();
$user = User::find($id);
$user->dosen()->delete($dosenUpdate);
    return redirect('admin/dosen')->with('message', 'Data berhasil dihapus!');
}
```

when i use that method, data from table dosen is deleted. but in table users there's still data . if i changed my method to :

```
 public function destroy($id)
{       
$dosenUpdate = Request::all();
$user = User::find($id)->delete();
$user->dosen()->delete($dosenUpdate);
    return redirect('admin/dosen')->with('message', 'Data berhasil dihapus!');
}
```

i got error :

```
  Call to a member function dosen() on boolean
```

what is the right code?

Comment: Seems it doesn't find user with passed id.. so result is `false`. Add `if ($user) {...then delete}`

Comment: does `user` and `dosen` have 1 to 1 relationship ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `destroy()` method you are storing the Boolean value in `$user` instead of User Model, as you are deleting the model in following line

```
$user = User::find($id)->delete();
```

This line is deleting the user model and returning the status of query i.e. if it is successful or not. Hence, `$user` is storing the status of `delete()` method and not the `user` model

change your `destroy()` method to below:

```
public function destroy($id)
{       
$dosenUpdate = Request::all();
$user = User::find($id);
$user->dosen()->delete($dosenUpdate);
$user->delete();
    return redirect('admin/dosen')->with('message', 'Data berhasil dihapus!');
}
```